# Showing list of nonpersistent objects in xaf

Tags: c#, listview, xaf

I want to show a listview of nonpersistent objects using xaf. I have a nonpersistent class. I want to show it as a listview when a popup window is popped. So far I couldn't manage to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you have so far and try to explain where you have problems with your existing code!

Comment: Please learn to be kind to people rather than using exclamation marks. Youı don't have to help me @derape

Comment: Well I don't think I have been rude, I just tried to tell you to improve your question that people here on SO are more likely to be able to help you. If you have trouble to improve it, you can have a look at how to ask questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See also a simpler, but more powerful solution using the NonPersistentObjectSpace.ObjectsGetting event from the following topics: [How to: Display a Non-Persistent Object's List View from the Navigation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument114052) [How to: Display Non-Persistent Objects in a Report](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument114516)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a full example in the DevExpress Support Center: [How to: Display a List of Non-Persistent Objects](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E980). You can even [run it online](https://codecentral.devexpress.com/E980).

The bulk of the solution is this:

```
public class ShowDuplicateBooksController : ObjectViewController<ListView, Book> 
{
    public ShowDuplicateBooksController() 
    {
        PopupWindowShowAction showDuplicatesAction = 
            new PopupWindowShowAction(this, "ShowDuplicateBooks", "View");
        showDuplicatesAction.CustomizePopupWindowParams += showDuplicatesAction_CustomizePopupWindowParams;
    }

    void showDuplicatesAction_CustomizePopupWindowParams(object sender, CustomizePopupWindowParamsEventArgs e) 
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach(Book book in View.CollectionSource.List) {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(book.Title)) {
                if(dictionary.ContainsKey(book.Title)) {
                    dictionary[book.Title]++;
                }
                else 
                    dictionary.Add(book.Title, 1);
            }
        }
        DuplicatesList duplicateList = new DuplicatesList();
        int duplicateId = 0;
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> record in dictionary) {
            if (record.Value > 1) {
                duplicateList.Duplicates.Add(
                    new Duplicate() {
                        Id = duplicateId,
                        Title = record.Key, 
                        Count = record.Value });
                duplicateId++;
            }
        }
        e.View = Application.CreateDetailView(Application.CreateObjectSpace(), duplicateList);
        e.DialogController.SaveOnAccept = false;
        e.DialogController.CancelAction.Active["NothingToCancel"] = false;
    }
}
```

For all things DevExpress, you should try their [support center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) first.

Comment: Thanks @shamp00 ,  I actually did it like this example yesterday and it works